# Define: "Operation"?

Tags: computer-science, operation

I came across this statement, not sure if he used the word correctly but I've seen it before and don't fully understand it.

> The key difference between statically-typed and dynamically-typed languages is whether **operations** get checked at compile time or at run time.

What exactly does "operation" mean in regards to CS?

I'm familiar with operators and know that `2 + 2` is an "operation" *mathematically* because it uses an operator to calculate a value.

But how exactly does an "operation" relate to values, expressions, and statements?

Is any statement an operation? `print 'hello world'`

Is any value/expression on operation? `'hello world'`

Comment: You are reading way too much into this. It is just the standard English meaning of "operation": something which does something to something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, any expression that evaluates a variable's value could be said to be an "operation" against that variable.  So basically, any use of the variable.

If you think about what dynamic languages do, it makes sense - they need to introspect the variable and determine its type at run time, when "operating" on the variable.  Statically typed languages don't need to introspect - at compile time, they "know" the type.

I suppose an identity expression (`x` or `"hello world"`) also qualifies as an evaluation of the variable, though one without an apparent purpose.  It may well be optimized out at runtime in a non-interactive environment

Comment: that makes sense. still wondering if either example (in question) is an operation? or does a variable need to be involved?

Comment: also isn't 5 + '3' an operation? that doesn't involve a variable and would be one of the things 'checked' before run-time.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to say "any expression".

Comment: so in the above context isn't he basically just saying that it checks the code (at compile vs run)?

Comment: @JBallin, a hard coded value like `"5"` or `3` is fundamentally the same as a variable `a` under the covers.  Although _you_ don't make  it a named variable, the interpreter will attach some identifier to the value as it processes the code.  Operations happen to 'variables' only inasmuch as they operate on their values - in one way or another.